# Search string and save it in array in Perl

Tags: perl

My text file looks like :

```
Register : STATUS
FIELD:ON   VALUE : 1
FIELD:COMPLETE  VALUE:0

REGISTER : CONTROL<br>
FIELD:SYSTEM_EN    VALUE:1
FIELD:CLOCK_EN     VALUE:0
```

Here I want to search for `REGISTER`and save the register name in `@register` and search for the respective fields name and their values and save them.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
open(my $log, "<", "register.log");
my $reg_string = "Register"; 

while (<$log>) { 
    if (/reg_string/) { 
        my $str = $_; 
        my @registers = split / /, $str; 
        print "\n $registers[3]\n";
    } 
}
```

Now I am trying to access array elements in the foll. way :

```
while(<$log>){
my $str =$_;
my @reg_string = split/\s+/,$str;
push(@reg_value, $reg_string[4]);
foreach my $i(@reg_value){
print " $reg_value[$i]";
 }
}
```

But this code gives me error 
Argument is not numeric in array elememt. (Its all string elements in my array)
I know I must be missing on some basic syntax as I am writing code using online tutorials. Pls rectify the code.

Comment: Did you tried anything on your own? Please show your efforts.

Comment: People are always willing to help on stackoverflow, but you have to show some effort, like having attempted to solve the issue yourself and then people will help show where you have gone wrong.

Comment: which is field and which is value on your example?

Comment: I am new to perl and spent the day in learning some basics and ended up doing something like this :
open(my $log,"<","register.log")
my $reg_string ="Register";

while(<$log>){
if(/reg_string/){
my $str = $_;
my @registers = split / /,$str;
print "\n $registers[3]\n"
}

Here I got print of all my Registers from log file. Now I want to save all Registers in some array which then I can access using the index. Once I achieve this, then I will figure out about fields.

 ON/COMPLETE are fields of STATUS register while SYSTEM_EN and CLOCK_EN are fields of CONTROL register .

Comment: My question is how to split the field for eg: `Register : status` in the text  `status` is the value right? Hence after the first semicolon is the value.

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include code instead of posting it in comments. I went ahead and did that for you.

Comment: `push(@reg_value, $reg_string[4]);` could you please explain why should you storing the 4th value.

Comment: @ssr1012 : I want the 4th element from the split. It has no relevance to my previous code.

Comment: list out the fourth elements in your samples.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Stored full line in arrays for Registers

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my (@full_line,@only_values) = ();
while(<DATA>)
{  push(@full_line, $_=~m/(register\s*\:\s*(?:[^\n]*))\n/i);  }
print join "\n", @full_line;

Output:
Register : STATUS
REGISTER : CONTROL<br>
```

> Stored values after the semicolon in arrays for Registers

```
while(<DATA>)
{  push(@only_values, $_=~m/register\s*\:\s*([^\n]*)\n/i);  }
print join "\n", @only_values;

Output:
STATUS
CONTROL<br>


__DATA__
Register : STATUS
FIELD:ON   VALUE : 1
FIELD:COMPLETE  VALUE:0

REGISTER : CONTROL<br>
FIELD:SYSTEM_EN    VALUE:1
FIELD:CLOCK_EN     VALUE:0
```

Please check and modify based on your requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Though it was not exactly I was looking for but your code gave me some lead to achieve what I wanted. Now I am facing issues with array elemet access using foreach loop. Pls help on that

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach my $i (@reg_value) {
  print " $reg_value[$i]";
}
```

I guess this is the code that is throwing your "Argument is not numeric in array element" error.

Using a `foreach` loop like this, each time round the loop, `$i` will contain one of the elements from `@reg_value`. Not the index to one of the elements, but the element itself. Try this instead:

```
foreach my $i (@reg_value) {
  print " $i";
}
```

Note that I'm just printing `$i`, not using it to look up an element in the array.

If you do want to get the indexes from the array, use code like this instead:

```
foreach my $i (0 .. $#reg_array) {
  print " $reg_value[$i]";
}
```